# Differentiate between Module and Class

Tags: ruby, testunit

The following yields an error:

```
require 'test/unit'

Test::Unit.setup_argv(["tests"])

$ run_tests.rb:4: undefined method `setup_argv' for Test::Unit:Module (NoMethodError)
```

How can I make Ruby use the `Test::Unit` class instead of the `Test::Unit` module for the method call?

**EDIT** Ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is that setup_argv is not available in Ruby 1.8.7.
Test::Unit is always a module. There is no class.

See the 1.8.7 docs here for how to use:
http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_8_7_330/Test/Unit

Comment: Thanks! Would it have worked with 1.9? How does Ruby differentiate?

Comment: It would have worked in 1.9, becase setup_argv is a module method there. Ruby does not differentiate. You can't have a symbol be a class and a module at the same time. It will be one or the other, so there's no need to differentiate. Instead you can define methods on both modules and classes, in this case for 1.9 setup_argv is defined as a method in the module, so it works :)